# How do I make floating text?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried other ones by using invisible armor stands, but when I type my own custom name, it shows the name: Armor Stand.

How do I get it to display my custom name?

Comment: What exactly is your question? I guess you think that you posted this under something else, but you didn't, this is a complete separate thing. We have no idea what you're referring to.

Comment: I mean like MC vanilla servers, they have floating text.

Comment: In what way is my name special?

Comment: Is that a Swedish name_

Comment: No, but this is also not really the place to discuss that. If it's important to you, you can contact me through one of the links on my profile (since you can't access the chat yet).

Answer (score 0):

First you can put it in a command block or type it out. Using invisible armor stands you type:

```
/summon armor_stand [x] [y] [z] {Invisible:1,Marker:1,CustomName:"Name",CustomNameVisible:1}
```

If you want it to be a color you have to type out these commands:

```
/scoreboard teams add {TeamName}
/scoreboard teams option color {TeamName} {Color*}
/summon armor_stand [x] [y] [z] {Invisible:1,Marker:1,CustomName:"Name",CustomNameVisible:1,Team:"{TeamName}"}
```